# What is the term for repetition of an initial syllable in successive words?

Tags: figures-of-speech, alliteration

In Anne Tyler’s *[A Spool of Blue Thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Spool_of_Blue_Thread)*, one character comments on the name of another

> Carla Carlucci: alliteration. Or something more than alliteration, but I don’t know the term for it.

*[Alliteration](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/alliteration)* is

> the use of the same consonant (consonantal alliteration) or of a vowel, not necessarily the same vowel (vocalic alliteration), at the beginning of each word or each stressed syllable in a line of verse, as in around the rugged rock the ragged rascal ran.

*Collins*

*[Homeoteleuton](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/homeoteleuton)* is

> the use of word-endings that are similar or the same, either intentionally for rhetorical effect or by mistake during copying of text.

*Collins*

An example is found in Ursula K. LeGuin's *[The Lathe of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeoteleuton)*

> He arrived at ideas the slow way, never skat*ing*
>   over the clear, hard ice of logic, nor soar*ing*
>   on the slipstreams of imagination, but slogg*ing*,
>   plodd*ing* along on the heavy ground of existence.

Obviously there is alliteration present in Ms. Tyler’s example, but it does seem like something more, deserving of its own nomenclature. Is there a standard term for the repeated use of a syllable at the beginning of successive words?

Comment: Other possibilities: 'assonance' is the term for repetition of vowel sounds. 'rhyming' is for similar ends of words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Rhyme** — [Literary Devices](http://www.literarydevices.com/rhyme/)

> Rhyme is a popular literary device in which the repetition of the same or similar sounds occurs in two or more words, usually at the end of lines in poems or songs.

But it's not restricted to word endings. Rhymes can be of many types.

For example, [Rhymer](http://www.rhymer.com/) gives the following taxonomy:

> 1. End Rhymes (*blue*/*shoe*)
> 2. Last Syllable Rhymes (*timber*/*harbor*)
> 3. Double Rhymes (*conviction*/*prediction*)
> 4. Triple Rhymes (*transportation*/*dissertation*)
> 5. Beginning Rhymes (*physics*/*fizzle*)
> 6. First Syllable Rhymes (*carrot*/*caring*)
>
> [Italicization of mentioned words added]

Your example of *Carla*/*Carlucci* is an example of ***First Syllable Rhyme*** (for example, *carrot*/*caring*). [Rhymer](http://www.rhymer.com/) explains:

> Words with first syllable rhyme have the same sounds preceding the first syllable break. For example, if you enter the word *explanation* using this option, *Rhymer* retrieves a list of words with the sound *ex* (e.g., *excavate*, *exhale*, *expert*, and *extra*). Other examples of first syllable rhyme include:
>
> - *pantaloons*/*pantomimes*
> - *highlight*/*hydrant*
> - *tulip*/*twosome*
>
> [Italicization of mentioned words added]

Alternate names for *first syllable rhyme* might include:

- **beginning syllable rhyme**
- **initial syllable rhyme**
- **head syllable rhyme**

Comment: Good answer. You might add that *beginning rhyme* is also known as *head rhyme* and *initial rhyme*. To make it clear that the rhyme is happening on the initial *syllable* (as opposed to just the consonant), you might call it ***syllabic** head rhyme* or ***syllabic** initial rhyme*.

Comment: +1 Actually, type 6 in your link, **first syllable rhymes**, seems to be more on point. However, the prime example given, *carrot/caring* does not rhyme to my AmE ears, unless we are talking about visual rhyme.

Comment: @bjb Really? I have the same first syllable in *carrot* as I have in *caring*. Where are you originally from?

Comment: @tchrist New Yawk. While I am comfortable with visual rhyming while scanning poetry, in other forms the vowel sounds need to be a close match for me to consider it a rhyme. *Carrot* has a very broad *a*, as in *package*, while *caring* sounds more like *pairing*.

Comment: @bib Curious; are you one of those easterners whose *Larry* has the vowel of *fat* not the vowel of *fate* like the rest of us have?   For me, *carrot* sounds just like *“care it”* —  because both my *caring* and my *carrot* have a tense vowel not a lax one, so [ˈkʰeɹᵻŋ] and [ˈkʰeɹᵻt]. The only difference between those two is in the final consonant, although because it is unvoiced in *carrot* that may shorten the previous vowel a bit compared with what happens in *caring*, which ends with a voiced consonant.

Comment: @tchrist *Larry* **IS** *fat*! And [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=carrot) says *carrot* is pronounced  (kăr'ət).

Comment: @bib I am merely describing how real people actually speak, not telling them how they are “supposed” to. Your vowels are obviously quite distant from my own. To someone from the [Inland North](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English) like me (specifically the Kenosha area of southeastern Wisconsin), hearing [æ] for [e] in those words always sounds like either a mistake or an affectation. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) for regional variants.

Comment: The car in carrot does not rhyme with that of caring.....

Comment: This whole carrot vs. caring thing is the [Mary-marry-merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Mary.E2.80.93marry.E2.80.93merry_merger). Different English speakers have or don't have it. For someone who has it, carrot and caring have a first syllable rhyme.

Answer (score 3):

I know of no term *from prosody* for the repeated use of a syllable at the beginning of successive words, but I imagine that there must be one.

In absence of a term *from prosody*, you might call this a ***reduplicated syllable*** or a ***reduplicated initial (syllable)***.

***Reduplication*** is a [technical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) from linguistics to describe syllable or root compounds like "papa" and "pee-pee" which compound the same syllable or root twice. A subtype of reduplication is ***rhyming reduplication***, which encompasses phrases like

> hokey-pokey, razzle-dazzle, super-duper, boogie-woogie, teenie-weenie, walkie-talkie, hoity-toity, wingding, ragtag, easy-peasy (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication))

Your example of

> Carla Carlucci

seems akin to the rhyming reduplication examples, except that the reduplication happens on the initial syllable. This is why I suggest ***initial (syllable) reduplication***.

Answer (score 1):

**Adnomination** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adnomination)

> Adnomination is the repetition of words with the same root word.
>
> *"News is what **some**body, **some**where wants to suppress; all the rest is advertising."* — Journalistic saying

Comment: Do *Carla* and *Carlucci* "have the same root"? Maybe. But the "same root" restriction would probably block the word from applying to a lot of examples the OP would want to apply it to ("and Andy", for example)