# Term for extended alliteration - a specific form of assonance

Tags: terminology

In answering a [recent question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480772/48571) I found myself in need of a term for alliteration but including the first vowel sound, as in "Costa Coffee". An ideal term would be more specific than *assonance*. I've seen *head rhyme* used but Wikipedia at least says that's just the same as alliteration. Does such a term exist?

Comment: See if these answers help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334390/what-is-the-term-for-repetition-of-an-initial-syllable-in-successive-words

Comment: @KarlG thanks, it's clearly a dupe, but I don't think the accepted answer is structured very well to answer either question (it leads with a big, bold and very general term, only getting to the real answer half  a screenful later)

Comment: I thought the term might be something like _syllabic alliteration_, but that’s not in use.

Answer (score -1):

There's only one term for this case - ***ALLITERATION***.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***alliteration***

: the repetition of usually initial consonant sounds in two or more neighboring words or syllables
 (such as wild and woolly, threatening throngs)
— called also head rhyme, initial rhyme

***ASSONANCE***

: relatively close juxtaposition of similar sounds especially of ***vowels*** (as in "rise high in the bright sky")
b: repetition of ***vowels*** without repetition of consonants (as in stony and holy) used as an alternative to rhyme in verse

Comment: Surely you can provide a better answer than this. If you've been teaching a course on it, you shouldn't have any problem clarifying. Just *trust me* isn't good justification for an answer.